# ¿Cómo hacer varios formularios para un mismo modelo en un ListView?

Tags: html5, django, django-forms, template

Quiero que me aparezca un listado de capacitaciones y un botón donde el usuario pueda registrarse en las capacitaciones que él desee.

### Modelo (**models.py**):

```
class Training(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Titulo', max_length=100)
    register = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='register', blank=True)


class Profile(User):
    picture = models.ImageField()
```

### Formulario (**forms.py**):

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    register = forms.BooleanField(label='Registrarse', required=False)
    training = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=False)
```

### Vista (**view.py**):

```
class TrainingListView(ProfileMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'training/training_list.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('training:list_training')
    form_class = RegisterForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrainingListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['training_list'] = Training.objects.all()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        id_training = form.cleaned_data.get('training')
        register = form.cleaned_data.get('register', 'None')
        profile = Profile.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
        training = None
        if id_training:
            training = Training.objects.get(pk=id_training)
        print(training)
        print(id_training)
        if register and id_training:
            print('se ha registrado a ' + str(register))
            training.register.add(profile)
        elif register != 'None' and training:
            print('ha dejado de estar registado a ' + str(register))
            training.register.remove(profile)
        return super(TrainingListView, self).form_valid(form)
```

### Template (**training_list.html**):

```
{% for training in training_list %}
    {{ training.title }}
    <form method="post" id="form_register">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>
            {{ form.training }}
        </label>
        {{ form.register }}
        <label for="{{ form.register.id_for_label }}">Registrarme</label>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('#form_register');
        var register = $('#{{ form.register.id_for_label }}');
        var training_pk = $('#id_training');
        training_pk.val('{{ training.pk }}');
        training_pk.addClass('hide');

        {% if profile in training.register.all %}
            register.prop('checked', true);
        {% endif %}

        register.click(function () {
            form.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Quiero que cuando el usuario dé un click en el `checkbox` se haga una petición *POST* al servidor y se modifique **Training.register** dependiendo del valor de este, pero como en cada iteración los objetos del formulario tienen el mismo `id` la aplicación web no funciona como quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, después de tanto navegar di con la solución, solo tenía que iterar el formulario y añadirle un número para identificarlo porque creaba varios formularios con el mismo id

```
{% for training in training_list %}
    {{ training.title }}
    <form method="post" id="form_register{{ foorlop.counter }}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>
            {<input type="text" id="id_training{{ forloop.counter }}" name="training">
        </label>
        {{ form.register }}
        <input type="checkbox" id="id_register{{ forloop.counter }}" name="register">
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('#form_register{{ forloop.counter }}');
        var register = $('#{{ form.register.id_for_label }}{{ forloop.counter }}');
        var training_pk = $('#id_training{{ forloop.counter }}');
        training_pk.val('{{ training.pk }}');
        training_pk.addClass('hide');

        {% if profile in training.register.all %}
            register.prop('checked', true);
        {% endif %}

        register.click(function () {
            form.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
{% endfor %}
```